# Is the zombie lord a zombie?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

We played the Zombie haunt (21) last night and found a hitch. The rules say the Heros win if they

> ...kill the zombie lord or all the zombies...

I went on an axe murdering spree and nailed all but one of the zombies before dying (such a good game!)

But at as my sole other companion ran the spear through the last zombie (with the zombie lord in the *next room over!*) and declared we had one, the traitor cried foul. They said that the zombie lord was a zombie, and 'Killing all the Zombies' meant they had to be vanquished too.

We argued that if the zombie lord had to be killed regardless it would have simply said 'Kill the Zombie Lord'. Eventually they relented.

What is the logic behind not having to kill the zombie lord? Was our decision right?

Comment: The logic behind it is that with no minions to control, the zombie lord is useless.

Comment: @Samthere but he's not, he's prety good at attacking people.

Comment: Well, he can still function, but his life goals have been crushed :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, the Zombie Lord is not a zombie.

As you said, logically he wouldn't be a zombie, because if he was they would just say **kill the zombie lord** for the requirements for winning the game ([page 25](http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/BHH_SurvivalRev_120105.pdf))

Additionally, the rules for that haunt remind you that the **Holy Symbol** that affects **all Zombies**, doesn't affect the Zombie Lord:

> If you have the Holy Symbol, all Zombies who make Might attacks against you roll two fewer dice. (This doesn't affect the Zombie Lord.)

It hasn't been confusion for many other players, so no additional information appears in the [FAQ](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=ah/faqs/hoth), or on [BGG regarding](http://boardgamegeek.com/spsearch.php?objectid=10547&objecttype=thing&q=%22Zombie%20Lord%22&searchauthor=&forumid=66&searchfield=all&displayresults=excerpt&B1=Submit) the Zombie Lord.

Comment: The confusing thing for me, was that he's the **Zombie** lord...

Comment: @Pureferret So was Jackie Chan was playing a dragon in [Dragon Lord?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Lord) :)

Comment: @Tacroy, yes. Yes he was.